# Link with OpenCV via CMake ExternalProject_Add

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I need to include OpenCV into my cmake-based project ,
this command which I used for that.

```
ExternalProject_Add(
        opencv
        PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
        TIMEOUT 10
        UPDATE_COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} pull
        BUILD_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

however my code could not find even includes

```
ExternalProject_Get_Property(opencv source_dir)
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE ${source_dir}/include CACHE INTERNAL)
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}
            ${OpenCV_INCLUDE}
        )
```

the code above for adding the includes.

seems I do not do something to make this working properly:

1. there are three subfolders in ext/opencv and this contains "include" with only one opencv.hpp which tries to include other modules but those ones located in modules/module_name/include/opencv2 so I don't think that I have to manually add each module dir to include dirs. suppose this should work from the box
2. ext/opencv-build, which contains built libraries but doesn't contain an inculdes, only one : opencv_modules.hpp

what should I add to the command to install this properly?
I suppose this is "install" step , but can you confirm and probably advise how to do this?

Comment: Your `set()` command is missing a quote `"` at the end.

Comment: it finds successfully the only opencv.hpp in include dir, primary question is how to add other includes

Comment: You overrode the build step command. Did you mean to build it, or are you just using this to download opencv headers? There's only one header because that's how it is in the git repo. I think opencv collects header files as part of its build.